# How to assign a Teacher Role as well as Student Role in moodle?

Tags: moodle

I have set the moodle in my localhost and want to add a user with a role teacher. How can i do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a user (site admin > users > accounts > add a new user)
2. Create a course (site admin > courses > manage courses and categories; create new course)
3. In the course enrol the user as a teacher (course admin > users > enrolled users; enrol users - select the role 'teacher' in the popup that appears)

Comment: You can also add roles to users already enrolled in a course. So after following the instructions above, you could add the "student" role by going to Course admin > Users > Enrolled users and clicking the little "+" icon (hover over it and it will say "assign roles". Then you can add the students role as well.

Comment: Hi davosmith.. What you answered is correct when i have a user with already assigned role with teacher but what i want is when i register a new user its by default register as student.. but i want to register that user as a teacher or assign a role of teacher to that user once get registered. Is it possible to do this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said above, when you enrol the user in the course, select 'teacher' if you want to enrol the user as a teacher on the course. As Lucien has also pointed out - you can go back to any enrolled user in a course, hover over the '+' symbol and add new roles to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you ask for is defualt role
in Moodle, default role is Authenticated user not student nor teacher [see this documentaion](https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Roles_settings#Default_role_for_all_users)
what enrolment method you are using?
if you are using for example, external database plugin , there is setting to change the default role [see this](https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/External_database_enrolment#Enrolment_and_roles)